# Not detecting aws-sdk library netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans-7, amazon-dynamodb

I'm coding a Java application using Netbeans. The database is hosted in DynamoDB (Amazon Web Services). I have downloaded the .jar file (aws-java-sdk-1.3.6.jar) from the Amazon website and tried to add it to my project. However, it is not working. I have followed the usual steps to add a .jar to a project (Tools -> Library -> New Library -> Add JAR/Folder). However, it does not seem to work. The imports I need to code the access to the DB are not recognised. I get the error "package com.amazonaws does not exist".

I have added other libraries (Xerces, for instance) following that method and used them without any problem. However, I am not able to make that one work.

Any help or suggestion will be very appreciated!!

Thanks!

Laura

Answer (score 0):

If you are limited to Netbeans try to follow the steps taken in response here: [AWS SDK on Netbeans](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=337489)

Another option is switch to Eclipse and use the Eclipse toolkit for AWS: [AWS Toolkit for Eclipse](http://aws.amazon.com/eclipse/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I finally got a solution but in a different way. I clicked on "dependencies" (listed on the left side) and then "add dependency". There I had to query "aws" and just install the matching result. After that Netbeans detected the library and the errors stopped.